# Is there a way to "pass" the user.name of auth0 user to a async function?

Tags: javascript, next.js, auth0, wp-api

I'm creating a next.js app which reads a custom post type from a wordpress multisite. I want when a user sign-in (using auth0), the name of the user to go in the wordpress URL to replace the "site" name.

**For example:**
I have this code in `utils/wordpress.js`

```
const BASE_URL = "https://fsm.xristosavgeros.com/sitename/wp-json/wp/v2/work";

export async function getPosts() {
  const postsRes = await fetch(BASE_URL + "?_embed");
  const posts = await postsRes.json();
  const filterPosts = posts.filter((post) => post.assigned_to == 'Johnny Worker');
  return filterPosts;
  }
```

What I need is something like this:

```
const BASE_URL = "https://fsm.xristosavgeros.com/ + user.name + /wp-json/wp/v2/work";
```

I think the way to go is `useUser()` hook but no matter where i tried to use it, the app crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the error when you say crash?

Comment: That hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. But when i call it from a function i can't pass it to the other function

Comment: Can't you pass the user name to `getPosts` as a parameter and replace `sitename` with that value?

Comment: The thing is that every user that logins with auth0 will have another site name! I also tried to fetch the `api/auth/me` page which have the user data in JSON but i get 401 not authorized.